# ASP.NET Arraylist <myobj>

Tags: asp.net, arraylist

can i use my own class in asp.net for Array list?

kind of:

```
Dim list1 As myobj= New ArrayList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generic List instead.

```
Dim list1 as List(Of myobj) = New List(Of myobj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the .NET 2.0 feature [Generics](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwilson/archive/2003/10/27/33926.aspx). Here is a couple of examples on how to use it [with VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w256ka79(VS.80).aspx)